# 20.04: Some keyboard shortcuts don't work in GNOME Shell desktop

Tags: gnome-shell, shortcuts, 20.04

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04. I'm wondering why file associated shortcuts don't work in the [GNOME Shell](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell) desktop.

For example: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, <kbd>Del</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, and <kbd>F2</kbd> do nothing.

But for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> works.

What's wrong, is it bug or feature?
How to enable it back?

Comment: I asked a similar question with additionnal problems, which was answered with a workaround that works great for me : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231413/basic-desktop-actions-not-available-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: That's opening the Nemo file manager app, which is not the GNOME Shell desktop.

Answer (score 2):

I associated this problem at first with the fact that I couldn't basically delete files, copy, cut or paste anything on the desktop. Here's the workaround that solved my problem once and for all:

1. Remove gnome extension:

   ```
   sudo rm -r /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/desktop-icons@csoriano/
   ```
2. Install nemo:

   ```
   sudo apt install nemo
   ```
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> in your **home** folder, enter the **.config** folder and create a folder in it labeled **autostart**
4. Open gedit and copy the following text into the empty file:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Type=Application
   Name=Nemo
   Comment=Start Nemo desktop at log in
   Exec=nemo-desktop
   OnlyShowIn=GNOME;
   AutostartCondition=GSettings org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons
   X-GNOME-AutoRestart=true
   NoDisplay=true
   ```
5. Save the text file as `~/.config/autostart/nemo-autostart-with-gnome.desktop`

And that's that. Next time you log in, nemo will be the one ruling over your desktop, not nautilus anymore. That means you'll have access to all the old shortcuts that were supposed to be working properly on your desktop, plus you'll have new options available when you right-click with your mouse. Worth giving a try!

I've come to this answer using this post as a reference: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/158#alternative-solution

Answer (score 1):

The feature set of the desktop as currently designed includes these keystrokes listed below as per [GNOME project documentation](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/CheatSheet). Others require additional steps to be added.

<kbd>System</kbd> AKA <kbd>Super</kbd> AKA <kbd>Windows</kbd>  Switch between overview and desktop

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> Switch between overview and desktop
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> Pop up command dialog
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> Pop up application switcher
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> Cycle in reverse direction in the application switcher
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> Switch between windows of the same application in Alt+Tab

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> Pop up accessibility switcher

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> Start and end screencast recording
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up/Down arrow</kbd> Switch between workspaces
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up/Down arrow</kbd> Move the current window to a different workspace
<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Right/Left arrow</kbd> resize & move window to take up right/left half of current workspace

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right/Left arrow</kbd> move window to right/left monitor

More combinations may be added. Go to **Settings**->**Devices**->**Keyboard**. You’ll see all the keyboard shortcuts here for your system. Scroll down to the bottom and you’ll see the Custom Shortcuts option, where you can add more.

Apps can add their own key combinations, For example, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> combination you mentioned is built into both [GNOME Terminal](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/adv-keyboard-shortcuts.html.en) and [VScode](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-linux.pdf).

Other desktops have other features and may have other keystroke combinations.

Comment: I was using only LTS Ubuntus. This worked in 16.04 (Unity), but also 18.04(some version of Gnome). I was able to create file on desktop and also delete it from there. I think this is crucial functionality since you are mostly working with desktop items.

Comment: Apps can add their own key combinations, For example, the Ctrl+Shift+N combination you mentioned is built into both GNOME Terminal and VScode.

Comment: How to simply delete a file, or copy paste, within the desktop, with the answer you suggest @K7AAY ?

Comment: @Raphaël Titol File deletion requires opening the File Manager, as that can't be done in the GNOME Shell desktop without the File Manager. Likewise, copy-paste is not a GNOME Shell function, and requires opening an app.