# "Open With Other Application" on Desktop not working as expected

Tags: gnome, 20.04, .desktop, desktop-icons

The current Ubuntu 20.04 behavior for "Open With Other Application" seems to work differently on the Desktop compared to Files/Nautilus.

Example: I configured VS Code IDE to be the default app for `text/plain` mime type (`~/.config/mimeapps.list`):

```
[Default Applications]
text/plain=code.desktop
```

Now, a right click -> `Open with Other Application` on a file `foo.bat` from the Desktop opens `gedit` without prompt, `Open` does not have any effect.

If I choose `Show in Files`, and do the same sequence, it works as expected - `Open` will directly open in VS Code, `Open With` asks for the application.

I don't really understand this behavior. How can I make Ubuntu behave the same way, regardless the environment, where the file is executed?

PS:  This issue is reproducible with other applications.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic desktop actions are not available on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231413/basic-desktop-actions-are-not-available-on-ubuntu-20-04) I would recommend to remove GNOMEs Hell from the computer.

Comment: Thanks for the info. This is unfortunate and irritating user experience - above behavior honestly behaves more like a bug than a missing set of features in GNOME Desktop Icons.

Comment: You can always report bug about this to launchpad and/or to GNOME GitLab. But this is very likely that this functionality will not be reimplemented in 20.04 LTS. So the solution is to switch to other DE. My favourite is MATE, your may prefer other.