# Can't run .desktop files

Tags: permissions, root, .desktop

I just installed Linux Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS in a virtual machine. I want to change my theme and my icons style. I downloaded  Unity tweak tool for that purposes. The tool is in `/usr/share/applications/Unity-tweak-tool.desktop`, but I can't run it. in fact I cannot run any .desktop file, and when I right click on a .desktop file and then go to permissions menu, I am not able to check the Execute: ''Allow executing file as a file'' field, it says ''You are not the owner, so you can't change these permissions''.

I want to log in as a root user(owner) and I tried typing `sudo -i` and `sudo -s` in the terminal and provided my password, but it didn't work.
How can I run .desktop files and is there a way to become an 'owner'??

Comment: Please run `ls -la /usr/share/applications/Unity-tweak-tool.desktop` and edit your question with your terminal results. You will see both "owner" and "group" in the results. This way we can say who is the owner and establish if it is you. They run `who am i` in the same terminal and provide the results in your question's edit, this is used to determine which user are you and know what to do next.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic desktop actions are not available on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231413/basic-desktop-actions-are-not-available-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make a `.desktop` file executable. It is not executed anyway but rather read by the system which will run the application indicated on its `Exec=...` line.

In Ubuntu 20.04, Unity tweak tool was replaced with Gnome Tweaks. So `/usr/share/applications/Unity-tweak-tool.desktop` is obsolete and replaced with `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.tweaks.desktop`.

Install it with `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`.

Solutions to run it then:

1. Press the Super/Windows key on your keyboard, which will open Gnome Dash. Then type `tweaks` and click on the Tweaks icon to run it.
2. Run `gnome-tweaks` in a terminal (found in `org.gnome.tweaks.desktop`)
3. In a terminal `gtk-launch org.gnome.tweaks` will launch the app through the `.desktop` file