# Ubuntu 20.04.1 / Desktop icons flicker when a file is deleted

Tags: gnome, 20.04, wayland, desktop-icons, flicker

I recently updated from Ubuntu 18.04.4 to 20.04.1. Now I noticed that the icons on the *Desktop* **disappear shortly** when I delete a file by pressing the <kbd>Del</kbd> key. There is **no** flickering when I delete a file in my *HOME* folder for example.

## Environment

- Window manager: Gnome 3.36.3
- Desktop environment: ubuntu-wayland
- Linux distribution: Ubuntu 20.04.1

## Maybe related

I also noticed that I cannot drag and drop files from the desktop into an open folder. I have to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> the files.

Comment: @N0rbert Yes, [pomsky's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1257195/18533) is really helpful. I will try out the [Desktop Icons NG (DING) extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2087/desktop-icons-ng-ding/).