# Ubuntu desktop right-click menu

Tags: unity

Where is the code that controls the right-click menu system? I understand that I can add menu items by editing .desktop files, but I would be interested to modify the system itself. My feeling is that the desktop shortcuts should be implemented as shell (eg bash) functions, so I want to find out what would be involved in implementing that.

Comment: If you are talking about 20.04 - check https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231413/basic-desktop-actions-not-available-on-ubuntu-20-04 also.

Comment: Are you using the Unity desktop, or are you using the default Gnome Shell desktop. Clarify and eventually update your tags. Also clarify your question: what right-click menus do you want to change? They are controlled by the individual application (can also be Gnome Shell), so check the source code of the application concerned.

Comment: That was enough to get me on the right track, which for me leads straight to Natilus. Thanks in particular, vanadium.