# How can we create app folder on the visible desktop itself in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS? (Not in app section, but on the desktop.)

Tags: gnome-shell

I am trying to customise my desktop. I have found a useful extension to make folder inside the app section named *appfolders management extension* but I am looking for something much more useful and handy. Is there a way we can **create app folder on desktop itself?** like we can do in Android OS? I mean to say that a folder that opens up on clicking and minimises on clicking outside. This can be very useful for quick access of app groups! If anyone knows any such extension, or method, I request them to write. Thank you very much. :)

One user has pointed out to me another answer but it is not this question. To explain my question further, I am posting image to explain this. Grouping of icons can be done inside applications section by an extension named **appfolders management extention**. The grouping of icons inside app section would look like this:
[image]

Now we want to achieve this on the desktop itself, not in the app section!! If we can create such icon groups on desktop, it will be easier to navigate and boost productivity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic desktop actions are not available on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231413/basic-desktop-actions-are-not-available-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: It might not be easier to navigate: your desktop is covered 99% of the time when you are working. The functionality you are after is fully implemented where it belongs: in the application overview.

Comment: How the desktop will be covered? I only wish to keep a few folders on desktop. :) Right now to find an application, I have to go to press the Super Key to enter in to the application zone to reach it so long. If it is directly available on the desktop, it will make work easier. We can make as many folders in android as we want on whichever screen we choose. Like we can make groups of apps based on certain criteria & it becomes easy to access them. The only thing is with one click it shall open the folder and just one click outside it should close the folder, exactly like in Android phones.