# How to open a URL by using drag and drop on desktop icons?

Tags: gnome, icons, .desktop

I want to create a desktop icon that runs a command when dragging a URL from the browser and dropping it on the starter icon.

I tried it by creating a `.desktop` file with the following line:

```
Exec=my-command %U
```

According to the documentation `%U` should be replaced with the file path / URL but it doesn't seem to work.

How can I pass URL arguments to a desktop icon in Ubuntu / Gnome?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: This is on Ubuntu 18.04 with Cinnamon desktop (installed manually).

Comment: Function was deactivated recently. I didn't go so deep to try a workarround on it, but can tell 1) here is the solution which worked on previous versions of Ubuntu (I have 20.04LTS) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393164/create-executable-bash-script-that-accepts-drag-drop , and 2) the reason behind this situation here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1257195/1124535