# Actual use of Software (such as Conky) AFTER installation

Tags: software-installation, conky

For something ALREADY ACTUALLY INSTALLED, how do I get it to run, put an icon for it on desktop etc?

My Software Manager tells me, for instance, that I have installed some GNOME clock though it certainly does not show on the desktop. Separately I have even used Terminal to install Conky.

But when I look for it using Activities it is Not Found.

What do I need to do get this stuff up and running?

Thanks.

Comment: Those seems like two independent questions. Pick one application, and open a new question for the other application. Please edit your question to provide specifics: Exactly what did you install, and how did you install it? Provide links to any instructions that you followed. Provide the details of any troubleshooting you already did.

Comment: You can see programs already installed on your system by clicking on the 9 dot icon at the bottom left hand corner of your screen and selecting from what is shown there. Right click on an icon in the list and you will see options such as adding to favourites which will add to the dock bar on the left of the screen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/q/64222/) and [Basic desktop actions are not available on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231413/basic-desktop-actions-are-not-available-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: Thank you for your answers which at least help me make some progress.

The suggestion to click at the bottom left corner and see what appears on the desktop certainly worked.
It did show a clock and I was indeed able to make it a favorite launch it. Problem is, it is NOT in a format I want.

Where I am coming from is that as far as I am concerned every OS MUST have a clock and calendar on the desktop.

Comment: I saw a YouTube video about Conky which looked like just the kind of thing I am looking for. It said the Terminal commands for installation were :

sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install conky-manager

I executed these commands WITHOUT getting error messages so I assume thje installation was successful.

However the problem is that when I did find Clock, as already mentioned, Conky was NOT there.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu isn't like Windows (idk about Mac) and has a nice desktop interface. Run it by hitting the super key (Or CMD or Windows) and simply search for it.

If you want to add a desktop shortcut:

Press the Super (or CMD or Windows) key

Start typing to search for the application

Right click

Create desktop shortcut or add to favorites for it to appear on your taskbar