# Drag and Drop to Firefox in 20.04

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, firefox, drag-and-drop

I see that other threads talk about icons and drag and drop errors to the Desktop. For me, it is the `Firefox browser`. I am not able to upload pictures to GitHub and a few other websites using `Drag and Drop` to Firefox in my 20.04.

I would be delighted if there is a workaround that does not include replacing Nautilus. I use 20.04 default because certain apps like `Blender` and `Android Studio` behave neatly on Ubuntu default and show some errors when using options like Kubuntu.

Update:

Created using Peek. When I drag and drop to the `Firefox icon` in the launcher, nothing happens, it comes back

> [image]

Update 2:

Tried the DING solution from the suggested link

Added DING and disabled default desktop icons extension through both `Tweaks` and `extensions.gnome.org`. The result was duplicate icons on the desktop and the same no `drag and drop` for Firefox.

Update 3: Tried this

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons
```

But the default extension stays. I do not know how to proceed further.

Comment: Confused about your question. I just created an image of your question using `screenshot tool` and was able to then drag and drop it into an answer dialogue box on your question (opened in FF). Is this about GitHub or Ubuntu?

Comment: It is not working for me, in Firefox - 20.04. I would be delighted if the above said is true for me as well. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic desktop actions are not available on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231413/basic-desktop-actions-are-not-available-on-ubuntu-20-04) . The best way to fix is to remove GNOME sHell.

Comment: Desktop Icons NG (DING) sounds good. I will try and update. Thanks.

Comment: I install DING, but the original Desktop Icons extension was not removable. So I had duplicate icons on the desktop and `drag and drop` to `Firefox` is still not working. I removed DING and everything is back to normal now.

Answer (score -1):

Simply do not use GNOME Shell for really productive work!

Use MATE instead. It is very flexible, configurable, modern while staying traditional for retrospective future.

Start with

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop^
```

then reboot and select MATE session in the greeter.

Then on MATE launch Firefox or any other application(s) to enjoy drag and drop or other basic functionality which is now removed from GNOME sHell.

Comment: Thanks. I was using kubuntu during last 6 months. I found out that a lot of things related to Android studio, Blender won't work in kubuntu and default Ubuntu is something we should have to use when trying non standard programs