# Suggest best version of Linux

Tags: 20.04

I was using Ubuntu LTS 20.04. I have countered many problems with this version of Ubuntu like Basic desktop actions are not available, etc. [hyperlink](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231413/basic-desktop-actions-are-not-available-on-ubuntu-20-04)
So, I want to download a new and better version of Linux. Please suggest me best version of Linux which I should use, which have almost no such issues.

Comment: If you want to use another distribution than Ubuntu, you should ask somewhere else than "Ask Ubuntu".

Comment: You can look at https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours for a list of flavors of Ubuntu you can use, but only you can decide what is *right* for you.  Your hardware (inc. processor, ram & more), your end-use goal, your chosen applications, plus your own tastes (likes/dislikes) will determine what's right for you. We're all different, so all tend to have a *favorite* desktop (or for a few of us, a number of *favorite* desktops - this box has 3 installed selected at login)

Comment: We do not accept questions where you ask for "best". That is a matter of opinion and you need to decide yourself what your opinion is. Besides that: all systems have the same software, just different default software.

Comment: To add to all the above, there is no 'best' Linux distro. There's only the best distro for *you*, and that's a very personal decision that you must make for yourself.