# Drag and drop to desktop, including images from browser

Tags: nautilus, .desktop

I'm trying to figure out how to drag and drop to the Ubuntu desktop.

I installed this extension:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2087/desktop-icons-ng-ding/

I can drag and drop files to the desktop but not images from the browser, for example i click and drag an image from a webpage to the desktop. But this works when I drag and drop to the nautilus.

And also these extensions will not allow to disable trashcan and home folder.

Do you have any idea on why they disabled this to the desktop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic desktop actions are not available on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231413/basic-desktop-actions-are-not-available-on-ubuntu-20-04) Simply do not use GNOME Shell. Productivity with it is zero (0).