# Misbehaviour while moving desktop icons on 20.04.2 (GNOME 3.36.8)

Tags: 20.04, gnome, nautilus, dconf

Every time I move an item on the desktop into a subfolder it reorders all icons on the desktop. Also newly created folders or files are placed at a random position rather than where I right clicked. Also I can select multiple items but not move them. All of this is very annoying and confusing.

How do I fix this? I already tried digging in the dconf editor but wasn't able to find any settings for the desktop there.

Comment: You probably hit [this bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-flashback/-/issues/41). Unfortunately, the [GNOME team decided to remove desktop icons](https://markperez.dev/blog/organize-desktop-icons-ubuntu/), so we can expect more bugs on this regard. I suggest you forget using desktop icons or move to another desktop environment.

Comment: Wow this is frustrating. One more reason to move to a new distro soon I guess.

Comment: See if this gnome-shell extension helps... https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2087/desktop-icons-ng-ding/, you may also have to uninstall the original `Desktop Icons` extension (gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons), or you'll get double icons.

Comment: Thank you, @heynnema I already found that and it works great except it doesn't integrate with nemo. But I'll take that for now. Also, disabling the Desktop Icons extension was enough.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic desktop actions are not available on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231413/basic-desktop-actions-are-not-available-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: If you use nemo filemanager, then let nemo handle the desktop icons instead of a gnome shell extension.