# How to activate drag n drop in 21.04

Tags: 21.04, drag-and-drop

So below is my OS version and I've read that in this version of ubuntu there's a drag n drop function implemented. Somehow it doesn't work: I can't neither drag n drop files to browser upload window nor drag n drop them from folder to for an example desktop.
I know that there's gnome extension called Desktop Icons, but I can't install it because of en error that says:

> "Can't install "Desktop Icons" because this is an extension enabled by
> my current mode, I can't install manually any update in this session.
> "

[image]

thank you beforehand!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic desktop actions are not available on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231413/basic-desktop-actions-are-not-available-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: @N0rbert not really. Now it seems like i have two file managers but non of them can drag n drop =\

Comment: @N0rbert moreover all of my desktop icons are freezed now and I can't even click on them =\\\

Comment: How exactly are you trying to drag and drop?  I am running ubuntu 21.04 in a virtual machine and I can drag and drop files from Documents to Music;  Documents to Pictures and back the other way.  I need more precise info to help me to recreate the problem.  I can also drag and drop straight onto the desktop from Documents.

Comment: @VladVlad Status please...

Answer (score 1):

Drag and Drop has been a problem since Nautilus stopped handling the Desktop in Ubuntu 20.xx. Gnome-shell extensions have tried to take on that job, with limited success. Here's a newer version that might work for you.

Use the `Extensions` app to disable the original "Desktop Icons" gnome-shell extension.

Install "Desktop Icons NG" (DING for short) gnome-shell extension, which can be found at https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2087/desktop-icons-ng-ding/.

Right-click on the Desktop and choose "Settings" to set prefs for DING.