# Is it possible to add this file to my desktop?

Tags: 20.04, permissions, filemanager, restricted-access

I got Ubuntu 20.04.3 recently and I cant add this file to my desktop. I don't know where to start but this is my only discord.desktop on my computer and I need instructions to remove the: arrow, lock, and X mark. If anyone can help me with any part I would appreciate any and all help.

[image: problem]

This may also be useful:

[image: possibly useful info]

Comment: Hmm... have you tried restarting the computer and checking if it still exists? I'm running the same Ubuntu version, and occasionally I'll get weird files like that, that'll go away if I restart or reload the file browser.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic desktop actions are not available on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231413/basic-desktop-actions-are-not-available-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score -1):

I run popos! so this might differ but, open the . Desktop file with a tex editor and type in “” take your discord file and drag and drop it into terminal and copy the output. On a new line type “Exec=(output)” you can create new lines “Name=(what will show up on desktop)” “Type=application” For the image download the discord logo png online and drag and drop the file into terminal. It may be image or icon I can’t remember “image/Icon=(output)” make sure the .desktop file is in the desktop folder. Now right click on the file on your desktop and select “allow running or execution or something like that” If this helped let me know it’s a way to create shortcuts of files.

Comment: not sure how but when I was following your instructions I decided to check files again and there was a second discord.desktop that definitely wasn't there yesterday and it was unlocked and it worked as a shortcut