# I can't copy-paste or cut-paste

Tags: directory, copy, paste

I can't copy-paste or cut-paste any file from desktop,folder etc. to again desktop,folder etc. Can you help me ?

Comment: What is the problem ? Describe what you are doing and what results / errors you get. Where are you trying to paste to ? What are the access-rights and ownership at that directory / file

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which version?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04 . And ı want to  move any file ( like pdf,docx,folder) to other folder ( Disk D or another new folder ) . But when i pushed ctrl + c or right click - copy and when i pushed ctrl + v or right click- paste in target folder , It doesn't work. Files doesen't move. That's the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic desktop actions are not available on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231413/basic-desktop-actions-are-not-available-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score -1):

Open terminal, navigate to ~ by using `cd ~`. From here, use the terminal command `ls -lsa`.

In the output, verify that your permissions for Desktop appear as `drwxr-xr-x`. For example, mine looks like this: `4 drwxr-xr-x  4 username username 4096 Mar 13 22:02 Desktop`

If the permissions are not as above, type `chmod 755 /Desktop/`. This should change the permissions on your Desktop to allow you to read/write/execute.