# Possible to use keyboard arrow keys to navigate (move the selection of) desktop icons?

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, shortcut-keys, icons, desktop-environments

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop, which means I probably use Gnome 3 (or Gnome 4? who can tell these days), and Gnome Shell is my desktop (I guess), and Nautilus is my file manager (at least, I can type `nautilus` in the terminal, and I get a window, so that is probably it).

I have seen [Basic desktop actions are not available on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231413/basic-desktop-actions-are-not-available-on-ubuntu-20-04) :

> Unfortunately, desktop icons are completely broken (which is quite unexpected in a LTS release of Ubuntu) as instead of the file-manager (Nautilus) handling the desktop items, now a GNOME Shell extension handles them.

I guess the situation has not changed much from being "broken", in the sense that I've tried to drag icons from the taskbar (or is it called a panel? who would know these days) on the left to the Desktop, in hopes of getting a shortcut there - and it did not do a thing. Although, I do this rarely, and I can live with copying `.desktop` files from `/usr/share/applications` to desktop (and then giving them whatever permission there was so they run at all).

The thing is though, what I wanted to do was to use the keyboard arrow keys, to navigate/select desktop icons; this I want to do, because I want to use a remote control via FLIRC, which then appears as a USB HID keyboard over USB, and sends out keyboard codes - so I could in principle send out codes for the arrow keys from the remote control, and be able to navigate up/down/left/right wherever there is an icon on the desktop, and select it.

Unfortunately, arrow keys do not work in Gnome (?) Shell (?) Desktop (or whatever it is they use in Ubuntu Desktop, the vanilla one) for "iterating" through desktop icons (funnily, tried this in Windows, and it still works there).

So I was wondering:

- Is there another keyboard shortcut, that would allow me to iterate/move through desktop icons in Ubuntu 22.04?
- If not, what other Desktop Environment / File Manager (?) can I use, which will allow me to use keyboard arrow keys to navigate among (move the selection of) desktop icons? Is the suggestion in the linked post "make Nemo handle desktop icons" still applicable for Ubuntu 22.04?